# How to do unit test of 16 digit Generated Random number

Tags: java, unit-tests, junit, code

Here i'm facing one problem that i have to do unit testing of 16 Digits of  Generated Random( 9872 5432 8765 0987, 9852 7412 6587 2365.........n) number so these Random Number are generated from Sql queries, i have to check uniqueness How to do   unit testing for this scenario is there any approach, or code or tool to perform this operation please tell me with simple demo

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a site for asking people to send you demos that solve your problems.

Comment: What should you test? Test that the numbers are random or that they are unique and have a certain length?

Comment: You mentioned two requirements: number length and uniqueness.  Which one are you having trouble with?

Comment: i have trouble with Uniqueness  and more over how to perform this operation mens with code or tools so like this and sorry for asking demo but intention simple that i need approach to solve this problem in technical way that is most important .

Comment: I'm confused - what is your actual problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Validating the uniqueness implies testing all the combinations or at least enough to assert a certain level of confidence, which should take you between 50hrs to 100hrs with a desktop computer. And yet it wouldn't be enough to cover some cases if the generator where to rely on a timestamp. Instead of testing the uniqueness, you should validate the algorithm.

Comment: i have to verify such way that  if generated random number are  repeatedly occurring or not once they generated from sql queries(already developer did his job and these random number are like 5000 10000) take that random number and test the data

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any special tool. Just pure Java and some maths (or minimal search-over-the-internet-or-at-least-over-the-stackexchange skills).

**Here is your demo.**

You only need to rework it for your input and for Assertion mechanism of your unit-test framework.

```
public class TestNumbers {

    final static int numberLength = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] testArrayOk = new int[]{
            123,
            321,
            111,
        };
        int[] testArrayWithNoUnique = new int[]{
            123,
            321,
            123,
        };
        int[] testArrayWithWrongLength = new int[]{
                123,
                321,
                12,
        };

        testAll(testArrayOk);
        testAll(testArrayWithNoUnique);
        testAll(testArrayWithWrongLength);
        
    }

    static void testAll(int[] inputArray){
        testForDups(inputArray);
        testForLength(inputArray);
    }
    
    static boolean testForDups(int[] inputArray){
        Set<Integer> findDupsSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int item : inputArray)
        {
            if (findDupsSet.contains(item)) {
                System.out.println("Dup detected in array: " + Arrays.toString(inputArray));
                return true;
            }
            findDupsSet.add(item);
        }
        return false;
    }

    static boolean testForLength(int[] inputArray){
        for(int i: inputArray){
            if(1 + (int)Math.log10(i) != numberLength){
                System.out.println("Item of improper length detected in array: " + Arrays.toString(inputArray));
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Output:

> Dup detected in array: [123, 321, 123]
>
> Item of improper length detected in array: [123, 321, 12]

**Solutions are taken from:**

- Check for duplicates in array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951547/java-array-finding-duplicates
- Check for number length: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306727/way-to-get-number-of-digits-in-an-int